# How to pass variable for LIKE operator to accommodate a value and NULL values

Tags: mysql

I am having some troubling with filtering database information on my website. I have two tables, an equipment database `equipment_database` and qr codes linked to specific equipment `qr_links`. So I am using a search function to filter the data using a `LIKE` operator. In cases where all entries are selected I would use `%%` and when specific parts are searched would be `%search_pattern%`. The problem is that not all equipment have a matching qr code. Therefore when using the `LIKE` operator it does not return rows with NULL values and returns only entries that have a linked qr code. Searching the qr code is optional and all entries with or without qr codes should be returned. Here is an example of the MySQL query:

```
SELECT equipment_database.equipment_id, equipment_database.equipment_type, equipment_database.equipment_name, qr_links.qr_linked_with_id, qr_links.qr_link_code
        FROM equipment_database 
        LEFT JOIN qr_links 
        ON equipment_database.equipment_id=qr_links.qr_linked_with_id 
        WHERE equipment_database.equipment_institute_id=? 
        AND equipment_database.equipment_institute_branch_id=? 
        AND equipment_database.equipment_status=? 
        AND CONCAT (equipment_database.equipment_name, equipment_database.equipment_type, qr_links.qr_link_code) 
        LIKE ? 
        ORDER BY equipment_database.equipment_name 
        LIMIT ?, ?;
```

Is there any way that NULL values form the `qr_links` could be included when using the `LIKE` operator (so `%%` returns all values plus those with NULL values).
Thank you!

Comment: Why there is a String Concatenation in where clause

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing you query like below. Using MySQL IFNULL(column, "value to return if null") function, we can get an empty string returned instead of NULL.

```
SELECT equipment_database.equipment_id, equipment_database.equipment_type, equipment_database.equipment_name, qr_links.qr_linked_with_id, qr_links.qr_link_code
    FROM equipment_database 
    LEFT JOIN qr_links 
    ON equipment_database.equipment_id=qr_links.qr_linked_with_id 
    WHERE equipment_database.equipment_institute_id=? 
    AND equipment_database.equipment_institute_branch_id=? 
    AND equipment_database.equipment_status=? 
    AND CONCAT (equipment_database.equipment_name, equipment_database.equipment_type, IFNULL(qr_links.qr_link_code, "")) 
    LIKE ? 
    ORDER BY equipment_database.equipment_name 
    LIMIT ?, ?;
```

Comment: Yes I like the logic, implemented the solution, but getting a error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '")) ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in...` any ideas?

Comment: try using single quotations instead of double quotations , Ex:- IFNULL(qr_links.qr_link_code, '')